# mysql where clause field

Tags: mysql, field, where-clause

I am trying to understand a piece of mysql code:

```
Select * from tableA   
where type = 'blue'  
and status = 'confirmed' 
and statement   
and date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
```

Would would the "and statement" mean where statement is a field but without an =, or, and, >, < ect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the datatype of statement column ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a MySQL peculiarity that other database engines do not exhibit. In other DBMS the equivalent would be:

```
and statement<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty where condition, as above, is effectively the same as `AND LENGTH(statement) > 0`. So any non-empty value in the `statement` column will be returned.

Comment: Non-empty or non-zero.